# How to include cloned git repo in my app using aide-ide?

Tags: android, aide-ide, android-ide, aide

I found a good database library in github and i want to use it  in my future projects. After i cloned the repos to my phone memory using Aide-ide and setting the path for local maven i cant figure out how to include it in my project.
I am thankful for anyone helping me in this.

Comment: can u paste the library? i never heard of cloning a lib to a device and using it that way. you usually add it as a dependency.

Comment: Its an AIDE-ide feature, here is the link http://www.android-ide.com/tutorial_git.html

Answer (score 0):

Open your app's build.gradle file and add it manually. The developer should have typed it somewhere in the ReadMe. It looks like this:

```
    implementation 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
```